# SNMP Stopped working on Catalyst 3560

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, snmp

Got an alert from Observium this morning that one of our spine switches is down. Seemed a little strange. If this was the case, other things would be alerting too.

Turns out the switch is up and running, but after 2+ years it decided to stop responding to SNMP.

So i did the usual

```
no snmp-server

snmp-server community blah ro
snmp-server chassis-id <switch hostname>
snmp-server contact <blah@company.com>
```

Checked the log to make sure it started

```
<switch hostname>#sh log | i %SNMP-5
2y39w: %SNMP-5-WARMSTART: SNMP agent on host <switch hostname> is undergoing a warm start
```

Looks good, but SNMP is still not responding. SNMP counters don't change.

```
<switch hostname>#sh snmp
Chassis: <switch hostname>
Contact: <blah@company.com>
Location: <Switch Location>
121127521 SNMP packets input
    0 Bad SNMP version errors
    2 Unknown community name
    0 Illegal operation for community name supplied
    0 Encoding errors
    52622307 Number of requested variables
    0 Number of altered variables
    12869109 Get-request PDUs
    160 Get-next PDUs
    0 Set-request PDUs
121127516 SNMP packets output
    0 Too big errors (Maximum packet size 1500)
    0 No such name errors
    0 Bad values errors
    0 General errors
    121127473 Response PDUs
    0 Trap PDUs
SNMP global trap: disabled

SNMP logging: disabled
SNMP agent enabled
```

How can i get SNMP back to life without rebooting this switch?

UPDATE: Last night the switch died and fell off the face of the earth. I went to the datacenter this morning to troubleshoot and the console was full of following messages. It appears we may have a network loop somewhere that causes memory fragmentation. More troubleshooting needed.....

```
2y39w: %SYS-2-MALLOCFAIL: Memory allocation of 1696 bytes failed from 0x26C184, alignment 8
Pool: I/O  Free: 7432  Cause: Memory fragmentation
Alternate Pool: None  Free: 0  Cause: No Alternate pool

-Process= "Pool Manager", ipl= 0, pid= 5
-Traceback= 8A3600 BE91B4 BECE60 26C188 270A1C 270B70 758DA8 752FEC
```

Comment: Are any changes on the switch or on your network has been taken?, i guess, ACL modification, any rule on some firewall to block your 161 port??

Comment: @OrlandoGaetano Nope. Absolutely nothing. We use RANCID for config version control and I don't see a single change on switches or firewalls that would cause it in any way. There are also no ACLs on the Vlan1.

Comment: And you are able to sniff your network traffic??, i guess first, put your one like a snmp server and request some data and see the response, on second way, tried to see with a mirror or span port the snmp request received by your switch, and compare

Comment: Try to debug the packages: `debug snmp packets` and share with us the logs.

Comment: @IstvánFonyó looks like the switch died overnight :( I was planning to go more troubleshooting today, but woke up to an alert that the switch is inaccessible. Ping/Telnet not responding. Heading to the Datacenter to see how dead it is.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.